# Using if statement when using values from the database

Tags: php, html, sql, if-statement

I have a query that outputs the resulting data into a table. I have two fields in that table that are vital for this `if` statement: `Max Capacity` and `Current Capacity`. These are from our database, from the same table.

I want to write an `if` statement:

```
if (Max_C == Current_C){
   echo "Sorry, course is full.";
}
else{
   $insert = mysql_query ("insert into blahblahblah... ");
}
```

How do I do this? How do I specify the `max_c` and `current_c` from the db?

That section of code:

```
if($courseandtime) {  $max_e = $courseandtime['MaxEnrollment']; $current_e = $courseandtime['COUNT(REGISTERED.SID)']; } 

    if ($current_e < $max_e) {
        echo "
       <form action='register-exec.php' method='post'>
       <label>Time: $_POST[Time]</label><br>
       <input type='hidden' value='$Time' /><br><br>
       <label>Student ID:</label><br>
       <input type='text' name='SUCID' id='SUCID' /><br><br>
       <label>CID: $_POST[CID]</label><br>
       <input type='hidden' name='CID' id='CID' /><br><br>
           <label>SID: $row['SID']</label><br>
       <input type='hidden' name='SID' id='SID' /><br><br>
       <button type='submit'>Register</button>
       </form>
       ";
    }
    else {
        echo 'Sorry, were full!';
    }
```

Comment: are you asking how do the db query? or?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysql). If you care to learn, [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a quite good PDO-related tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the insert code:

```
    //Create query
    $qry="INSERT INTO table (column-name, another-column) VALUES ('$variable', '$valueyouwanttoinsert')";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    if ($result) {
    echo "Success!";
    }
    else {
    die("Query Failed");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using the following code:

```
//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM table WHERE column='$variable'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    $course = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $max_c = $course['max_c'];
        $current_c = $course['current_c'];
}
else {
    die("Query failed");
}
    if ($current_c == $max_c){
        echo "Sorry, the course is full!";
    }
    else {
        //MySQL Insert Code here
    }
```

Comment: thanks i will try this as soon as i get home again i need to go and buy something from the store for my mom.

Comment: oi can you explain the //mysql insert code?  do i have to do it like $insert=mysql_query (.....) ?

Comment: if i show you what i've done so far can you help me?  i'm having trouble :(

Comment: because i am getting current capacity as an output by doing a count on how many particular session IDs exist.

Comment: i have a query that finds a session for a course at a particular time.  i want to implement an if else statement where if there is room left in a session at the time the user enters, an insert query will fire if there is room.  if not, it will just say its full.  the max enrollment is pre determined, and the current enrollment is found by doing a count.

Comment: The else statement will add a number to the current number of people that have joined?

Comment: the else statement should allow the person to register for that class if the max enrollment is not equal to current enrollment.  so the else statement should insert the person's ID (sucid, which is given by the user), CID (again given by the user) and SID (found from the table) into the registered table.  once this is done it should also echo that it was able to add them to that class successfully.

Comment: Why do you have $_POST[SID] if the user isn't inputting it?

Comment: ugh my mistake.  how do i insert the SID i found earlier?  using $row[SID]?

Comment: Don't you just need a form for them to register that only displays if there is room, which will then register them?

Comment: in the html form, they enter their ID (sucid), cid, and time.  when they submit they are either able to register for that class at that time (they know the times, they're given to them) but if the class is full I don't want them to be able to register.  if class is full they won't be added, and told that class is full.  if class has spot, then they will be inserted into it and registered

Comment: Your question is quite broad. Could you please be more specific, ex: how do I do an insert query.

Comment: how do i implement an if/else statement where if the maxenrollment == current enrollment (which i get by doing a count of the SID) then the student can't register.  however, if they are not equal, then they should be able to register.

Comment: sorry i am really new to this :(